# I have followed google map tutorial but keep on getting this answer:Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: java, android, android-virtual-device

Ive been following a tutorial regarding google maps, a pretty basic tutorial here http://umut.tekguc.info/en/content/google-android-map-v2-step-step ,I am unable to run the application on the emulator, iv donwloaded and installed the vend.apk and the gms.apk files as well as also have downloaded the google play services from the SDK manager. After doing all this when i finally run my application on the emulator the following error occurrs :
"Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY".

I also have tried and change the AVD but it does'nt work. I think i am unable to configure the APIs properly with the AVD. Any help would be appreciated, thank you all.
Here is my code:
MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.googlemapsandroidv2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mMap=((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    final LatLng CIU=new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);
    Marker ciu=mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(CIU).title("My Office"));
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

 }
```

Here is the Manifest:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   package="com.example.googlemapsandroidv2"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

 <permission
    android:name="com.example.googlemapsandroidv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>


 <uses-permission
    android:name="com.example.googlemapsandroidv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <meta-data  
         android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
         android:value="AIzaSyCLhVm6faqwv8gaj1aWZ_Xvlsf4sMal42U"/>
         <uses-library
    android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.googlemapsandroidv2.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

   </manifest>
```

Here is the detail regarding the AVD:
Targert:Android 4.0(API level 14)
CPU/ABI:ARM(armeabi-v7a)

this is what i get on the console:

```
[2013-07-18 14:27:31 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] Android Launch!
[2013-07-18 14:27:31 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] adb is running normally.
[2013-07-18 14:27:31 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] Performing com.example.googlemapsandroidv2.MainActivity activity launch
[2013-07-18 14:27:31 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'MapTestAvd'
[2013-07-18 14:27:31 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'MapTestAvd'
[2013-07-18 14:27:33 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2013-07-18 14:27:33 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2013-07-18 14:28:29 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-07-18 14:28:29 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] Uploading GoogleMapsAndroidV2.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2013-07-18 14:28:40 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] Installing GoogleMapsAndroidV2.apk...
[2013-07-18 14:29:26 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
[2013-07-18 14:29:26 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2013-07-18 14:29:26 - GoogleMapsAndroidV2] Launch canceled!
[2013-07-18 14:34:40 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'addon-google_apis-google-14': File not found: manifest.ini
[2013-07-18 14:37:09 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'addon-google_apis-google-14': File not found: manifest.ini
[2013-07-18 14:54:40 - SDK Manager] Warning: Ignoring add-on 'addon-google_apis-google-14': File not found: manifest.ini
```

THANK YOU ALL FOR YOUR TIME. I really appreciate all sorts of help.

Comment: I suggest you try testing it on the device. Not sure how far vending.apk and gms will work on the emulator

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you create and use an AVD with a "Google APIs" Target.

Otherwise it will not find Google Maps.

[image]

If you do not get that option in your Target list make sure you've downloaded it from the SDK Manager.

[image]

Comment: i did that and also iv checked the sdk manager, google play services as well as the Google APIs for the version 14 15 16 17 are installed respectively now that i have changed the configurations, no i am getting this in the logcat:07-19 11:34:49.697: D/dalvikvm(652): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
07-19 11:34:51.027: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(652): Google Play services is missing.
07-19 11:34:51.046: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(652): Google Play services is missing.
07-19 11:34:51.056: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(652): Google Play

Comment: You need to use 4.2.2+. Check here: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html "Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services."